# What other values can we use in orderBy of google contacts api 3?

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I've tried orderby = "lastmodified" as specified in documentation, and it works.  However, any other values like "fullname" or "lastname" or "name", do not work.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference), in contacts API, the only supported value for orderby is "lastmodified".